# How to debug CentOS/AlmaLinux shutdown hang after disconnecting camera

Tags: linux, centos, alma-linux

I've got an annoying situation:

Default Server with GUI install of AlmaLinux 8.5.(kernel is 4.18.0-348.20.1.el8_5)

I'm using a USB camera (in my case, I'm using Cheese with an e-con See3CAM_11CUG).

I open the camera with Cheese, let it get to showing me the image from the camera (you don't have to record or anything), then unplug the camera.

At that point, I shut the system down. During shutdown the system will hang, AFTER systemd says things like 'Reached target Shutdown', 'Reached target Final Step' and 'Starting Power-Off'.
Once hung, if you leave it long enough you get some kernel 'INFO: task blocked for more than 120 seconds' messages from the kernel.

Closing Cheese before disconnecting the camera still hangs the system.
Only by leaving the camera connected (or never connecting it) can you avoid the hang.

I then installed an older version of CentOS 8, and found that C8 kernels up to and including 4.18.0-305.25.1.el8_4 worked, while C8 kernel 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5 is the first one that fails.

Any good ideas how to to debug or mitigate this? We develop a device based on Linux, and we can't have it hanging up on shutdown, especially after all the time we've spent trying to get our customers to not simply turn the things off.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a few other cameras in the office (both from Imaging Source) and neither of them produced the issue.

I also built and tested on each of the longterm supported kernels from kernel.org, none of which produced the problem.

At the moment my assumption is that the e-con camera (a camera we've had some issues with in the past) is doing something wrong, and the Alma kernel has a bad patch somewhere in it that causes the effect. I'm issuing a bug report to the Alma team and working around the whole issue by building 4.19. from kernel.org for my uses.